Does Dagger 2 supports Instrumented Test in Android?
Is it possible to use Dagger 2 Android for instrumented test in a multi module project? I can't see related articles and SO question so here it is.
Custom runner
/**
 * Custom AndroidJUnitRunner to register [TestApp]
 * */
class CustomTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {

    override fun newApplication(cl: ClassLoader?, name: String?, context: Context?): Application {
        return super.newApplication(cl, TestApp::class.java.name, context)
    }

}

Build Gradle (app module)
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner = "com.app.name.CustomTestRunner"
}

Build Gradle (common module)
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" // Default
}

DaggerApplication
/**
 * A DaggerApplication instance for testing
 * */
class TestApp : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        val appComponent = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
        appComponent.inject(this)
        return appComponent
    }

}

Component
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, // Default module, always on top
        TestAppModule::class,
        CommonModule::class // From common module
    ]
)
interface TestAppComponent : AndroidInjector<TestApp> {

    // Override the builder
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        // We can now access and inject Application class anywhere in this project
        // as long as that consumer class is also injected/registered in Dagger
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): TestAppComponent

    }

}

App Module
@Module(
    includes = [
        TestAssetModule::class
    ]
)
object TestAppModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("AppName")
    fun provideAppName(application: Application): String {
        return application.getString(R.string.app_name)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideTypeConverter(jsonParserRepository: JsonParserRepository): AppTypeConverter {
        return AppTypeConverter(jsonParserRepository)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRoomDatabaseInstance(
        application: Application,
        appTypeConverter: AppTypeConverter
    ): AppLocalDatabase {
        return Room
            .inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(application, AppLocalDatabase::class.java)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .addTypeConverter(appTypeConverter)
            .build()
    }

}

Modules
@Module
object TestAssetModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAssetRepository(
        dao: AssetDao,
        service: AssetService,
        mapper: AssetDataMapperList
    ): AssetsRepository = AssetsRepositoryImpl(dao, service, mapper)

    @Provides
    fun provideAssetMinRepository(
        dao: AssetDao,
        service: AssetService,
        assetDataMapperList: AssetDataMapperList, // Use for updating record in the table
        assetMinDataMapperList: AssetMinDataMapperList // Use for getting record on a fewer column form
    ): AssetsMinRepository = AssetsMinRepositoryImpl(dao, service, assetDataMapperList, assetMinDataMapperList)

    @Provides
    fun provideFakeAssetApi(
        parserRepository: JsonParserRepository
    ): AssetService {
        return FakeAssetService(parserRepository)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideAssetDao(db: AppLocalDatabase): AssetDao {
        return db.assetDao
    }

}

This builds but running the test class below fails
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@MediumTest
class AssetDaoTest {

    @Inject
    lateinit var database: AppLocalDatabase

    @Inject
    lateinit var assetDao: AssetDao

    @Inject
    lateinit var fakeAssetService: AssetService

    private lateinit var mapper: AssetDataMapperList

    private lateinit var entities: List<AssetDataEntity>

    @Before
    fun setup() = runTest {

        val testApp = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<TestApp>()
        val appComponent = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder().application(testApp).build()
        appComponent.inject(testApp)

        mapper = AssetDataMapperList(AssetDataMapper())

        val dto = fakeAssetService.getAssetItems("", "", "")

        entities = mapper.mapToEntityModelList(dto.data)

    }

}

Error:
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property fakeAssetService has not been initialized

Dagger graph shows links to both actual module and test module from  test class @Inject so what went wrong here?
